# Using sed with regex to replace text on OSX and Linux

Tags: regex, linux, macos, sed, makefile

I am trying to replace some strings inside a file with `sed` using Regular Expressions. To complicate the matter, this is being done inside a Makefile script that needs to work on both `osx` and `linux`.

Specifically, within `file.tex` I want to replace

```
\subimport{chapters/}{xxx}
```

with

```
\subimport{chapters/}{xxx-yyy}
```

(`xxx` and `yyy` are just example text.)

Note, `xxx` could contain any letters, numbers, and `_` (underscore) but really the regex can simply match anything inside the brackets. Sometimes there is some whitespace at the beginning of the line before `\subimport...`.

The design of the string being searched for requires a lot of escaping (when searched for with regex) and I am guessing somewhere therein lies my error.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
sed -i'.bak' -e 's/\\subimport\{chapters\/\}\{xxx\}/\\subimport\{chapters\/\}\{xxx-yyy\}/g' file.tex
# the -i'.bak' is required so SED works on OSX and Linux
rm -f file.tex.bak # because of this, we have to delete the .bak files after
```

This results in an error of `RE error: invalid repetition count(s)` when I build my Makefile that contains this script.

I thought part of my problem was that the `-E` option for `sed` was not available in the `osx` version of `sed`. It turns out, when using the `-E` option, fewer things should be escaped (see comments on my question).

Comment: **The `-E` option is available in `OS X`, which would be the `-r` option on Linux.**

Comment: @l'L'l when I use the `-E` option, I get a `not defined in the RE` error. Even if it was working for me, I would not have any way to set the option which is POSIX since OSX/BSD does it one way and GNU does it the other way.

Comment: That's because you are escaping the capture groups, which you don't need to do when using `-E` (eg. instead of `\( ... \)`, just do `( ... )`)

Comment: If you are using the `sed` command within a `Makefile` and want to use different ones based on the OS you can always use a conditional like: `UNAME := $(shell uname); ifeq ($(UNAME), Linux)`...

Comment: You aren't really changing your question — just correcting it, which is what the edit feature is for :) Maybe just put that you assumed it wasn't available on OS X, but to find out it does exist.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's is the version that ended up working for me.

```
sed -i.bak -E 's#^([[:blank:]]*\\subimport{chapters/}{[[:alnum:]_]+)}$#\1-yyy}#' file.tex
rm -f file.tex.bak
```

Much thanks go to @heemayl. Their answer is the better written one, it simply required some tweaking to get a version that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

POSIX-ly:

```
sed 's#^\(\\subimport{chapters/}{[[:alnum:]_]\+\)}$#\1-yyy}#'
```

- `#` is used as the parameter separator for `sed`'s `s` (Substitution)
- `\(\\subimport{chapters/}{[[:alnum:]_]\+\)` is the captured group, containing everything required upto last `}`, preceeded by one or more alphabetics, digits, and underscore
- In the replacement, the first captured group is followed by the required string, closed by a `}`

**Example:**

```
$ sed 's#^\(\\subimport{chapters/}{[[:alnum:]_]\+\)}$#\1-yyy}#' <<<'\subimport{chapters/}{foobar9}'
\subimport{chapters/}{foobar9-yyy}

$ sed 's#^\(\\subimport{chapters/}{[[:alnum:]_]\+\)}$#\1-yyy}#' <<<'\subimport{chapters/}{spamegg923}'
\subimport{chapters/}{spamegg923-yyy}
```

Comment: If I only want to edit the file `file.tex` in place, POSIX-ly, how would I do that?

Comment: @ScottWilton Do: `sed -i.bak 's#...' file.tex`, the original file will be backed up as `file.tex.bak`. Without backup: `sed -i '' 's#...' file.tex`

Comment: This isn't working for me. Both in the makefile, and in the following simple test (in bash on osx): `echo '\subimport{chapters/}{01_general}' | sed 's#^\(\\subimport{chapters/}{[[:alnum:]_]\+\)}$#\1-yyy}#''`. Which produces no change (`\subimport{chapters/}{01_general}`). Your examples above also don't work for me.

Comment: Ok, so `sed -i.bak -E 's#^(\\subimport{chapters/}{[[:alnum:]_]+)}$#\1-yyy}#' file.tex` works on my machine at least. Only problem is that there is sometimes spaces in front of `\subimport ...`. I tried adding `\s*` to the expression but it didn't work.

Comment: @ScottWilton `\s` is not POSIX. Do: `^\([[:blank:]]*\\subimport...`